# My android calculator app's ratio is strange

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableRow>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Edit1"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="첫번째숫자"
        android:textColor="#FF018786"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        ></EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Edit2"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:hint="두번째숫자"
        android:textColor="#FF018786"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        ></EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnNum0"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnNum1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/BtnNum2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnNum3"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnNum4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnNum5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnNum6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="6"
            android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>
        <Button

            android:id="@+id/BtnNum7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="7"
            android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnNum8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnNum9"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>
    </TableRow>



    <TableRow>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BtnAdd"
        android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_span="5"
        android:text="더하기" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BtnSub"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_span="5"
        android:text="뺴기" />
        </TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BtnMul"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_span="5"
        android:text="곱하기" />
    </TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BtnDiv"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_span="5"
        android:text="나누기" />
</TableRow>


<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BtnRem"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:backgroundTint="#6ADFD9"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_span="5"
        android:text="나머지" />
</TableRow>

    <TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TextResult"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="계산 결과:"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_span="5"
        ></TextView>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

this is my code,
and this is my app's blueprint

[image]

button 0 and 5 take up more space
they are bigger than others
how can i fix it??
i need tablelayout and
i need to put  android:layout_weight="1" to every component

Comment: `<TableRow weightSum="5">` ...while every other num-pad uses `3` buttons in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the attribute `android:weightSum="5"` in the parent in order to make `android:layout_weight="1"` work properly, try:

```
<TableRow weightSum="5">
```

With the weightSum attribute you define how many equal spots this element will have . Then using the layout_weight attribute in the children will define how many spots this element will occupy.

Also remember to add attribute `android:layout_width="0dp"` alongside `android:layout_weight="1"` in order to increase performance.